# Rewrite Rules just doesn't work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**Settings in httpd.conf is correct for .htaccess**

Here is the content of .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /  

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^Minecraft(Skin|Cloak)s/

RewriteRule ^Minecraft(Skins|Cloaks)/([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)(?:.*) /$1/$2.png
```

which I expected to get this result:

> Input: /MinecraftSkins/u5er_n4me-skin-317982479812
>
> Output: /Skins/u5er_n4me.png
>
> Input: /MinecraftCloaks/u5er_n4me-cape-317982479812
>
> Output: /Cloaks/u5er_n4me.png

But Nothing was happened, only a 404 returned and no rewrite working.

Is my Regexp wrong?

Log:
[Mon Sep 08 17:39:30.089346 2014] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 5212:tid 1108] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 192.168.1.1:57989] 192.168.1.1 - - [skins.jsw3286.info/sid#27866e0][rid#27dc240/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /MinecraftSkins/jsw-18947

[Mon Sep 08 17:39:30.089346 2014] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 5212:tid 1108] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 192.168.1.1:57989] 192.168.1.1 - - [skins.jsw3286.info/sid#27866e0][rid#27dc240/initial] pass through /MinecraftSkins/jsw-18947

[Mon Sep 08 17:39:30.090346 2014] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 5212:tid 1108] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 192.168.1.1:57989] 192.168.1.1 - - [skins.jsw3286.info/sid#27866e0][rid#27dc240/initial] [perdir F:/mcsrv/SkinStation/root/] strip per-dir prefix: F:/mcsrv/SkinStation/root/MinecraftSkins/jsw-18947 -> MinecraftSkins/jsw-18947

[Mon Sep 08 17:39:30.090346 2014] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 5212:tid 1108] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 192.168.1.1:57989] 192.168.1.1 - - [skins.jsw3286.info/sid#27866e0][rid#27dc240/initial] [perdir F:/mcsrv/SkinStation/root/] applying pattern '^Minecraft(Skins|Cloaks)/([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)(?:.*)' to uri 'MinecraftSkins/jsw-18947'

[Mon Sep 08 17:39:30.090346 2014] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 5212:tid 1108] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 192.168.1.1:57989] 192.168.1.1 - - [skins.jsw3286.info/sid#27866e0][rid#27dc240/initial] [perdir F:/mcsrv/SkinStation/root/] pass through F:/mcsrv/SkinStation/root/MinecraftSkins/jsw-18947

And then 404 is presented.

Comment: Please show the output of `RewriteLog` (which shows the steps the rewrite engine takes) + `error.log` (which shows the final path of the not-found page). (+ Did you reload apache config?)

Comment: @DanFromGermany It seems there is no rewrite...and I reload it a lot  log is here:     Cannot serve directory F:/mcsrv/SkinStation/root/MinecraftSkins/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive, referer: http://skins.jsw3286.info:25562/MinecraftSkins   -----and-----    File does not exist: F:/mcsrv/SkinStation/root/MinecraftSkins/jsw-18947.png, referer: http://skins.jsw3286.info:25562/MinecraftSkins/jsw-18947.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `RewriteCond` does not pass because `REQUEST_URI` begins with a leading slash (`/`).
Also, your `RewriteCond` is useless in your case so you can remove it.

Use this code instead

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/$2\.png !-f
RewriteRule ^Minecraft(Skins|Cloaks)/([a-zA-Z_0-9]+) http://skins.minecraft.net/Minecraf$1/$2.png [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^Minecraft(Skins|Cloaks)/([a-zA-Z_0-9]+) $1/$2.png [L]
```

Comment: Alright I need another rewriterule to redirect all the "Cannot Found" to skins.minecraft.net using 301 without timestamp numbers and type signs(-skin-|-cape-)

Comment: Could you give an example ?

Comment: Input:/MinecraftSkins/Notch-skin-123897124   Rewrite:/Skins/Notch.png (but not exist) then 301:http://skins.minecraft.net/MinecraftSkins/Notch.png

Comment: Why do you want to rewrite if it does not exist ? Can `Notch.png` exists in another example or is it always not found ? Because if it is, then you can do a redirect directly

Comment: It makes for non-exist fallback, for some examples it exists, but for another it doesn't. skins.minecraft.net is larger than skins.jsw3286.info so i need an upstream with priority.My server first,remote server last.

Comment: Make the word shorter, this is *merge*

Comment: You can try my edited answer. Hope i did understand you well. For example, if i go to `/MinecraftSkins/Notch-skin-123897124` it searches if `/Skins/Notch.png` exists. If so, it rewrites, otherwise it redirects (301) to `skins.minecraft.net/MinecraftSkins/Notch.png` (and it's the same for `Cloaks`)